# forbidden error while fetching YouTube videos list from the YouTube API?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube, youtube-data-api

i am calling youtube api to get list of youtube video data. but i am getting get 403 error. i also enabled YouTube Data API (v3).

I am trying to get a list of videos from YouTube using YouTube API. I am using an API key. When I use the URL below everything works fine and I get the desired results: GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=i7KKDpmnR7U&key=YOUR_API_KEY=snippet,statistics,contentDetails

but when i tried locally i am unable to print the success response in my console. i always getting error response as get 403 forbidden. Is there is any issue when we run in local environment? or there is any issues with the Api

something missing any hints would be Great!

### my code

```
$scope.youtubeApi = function(videoId){
    console.log('youtubeApi: ' + JSON.stringify(videoId));

    if (videoId) {
        //console.log('Youtube API Call function is called and Video is is : ' + videoId);

        var API_KEY = "AIzaSyCmsmxLnAnDxwQ6wzzzHnLEGBt7X8ce94wI10A";

        $http.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id="+ videoId + "&key=" + API_KEY + "&part=snippet,statistics,contentDetails").
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
           console.log('sucess call.' + JSON.stringify(data));
          //$timeout(parseresults(data), 500);
          //formObject(data);
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log('Error while saving this Video Id details in rest.' + JSON.stringify(data));
          console.log('Error while saving this Video Id details in rest.' + videoId);
        });
      }
  }
```

### error on the console

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden",
        "message": "Forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Forbidden"
  }
}
```

i am getting error only when i tried to run locally using $http.get() method. but when i manually tying the url with apikey and videoId on browser window(https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=i7KKDpmnR7U&key=AIzaSyBbyrB-WGvDSYrxHhEnQfcTuiyrDkF7LwI&part=snippet,statistics,contentDetails), got success response in browser ie video object.

Comment: Do you have any restrictions on the key? Normally when using an API key you set restrictions on where the request can come from by entering valid HTTP referrers/ IP Addresses/ iOs apps etc

Comment: Using your key it [seems to work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/GMan134/xfpLe1x4/)

Comment: I recommend going into your console and changing your api key. As now everyone has access to your key now. As to your problem, George has a valid point. As well as you can look at your local development setup as you might have restrictions in place that you need to change.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [YouTube v3 error document](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors). Error type 403 is a symbol of either `forbidden` or `quotaExceeded`. Please find below the description.

[image]

Hence, The channel specified by the `id (i7KKDpmnR7U)` parameter does not support the request or the request is not properly authorized.

```
                                       OR
```

The `videos.list` method returns a forbidden (403) error when an improperly authorized request tries to retrieve the details of a video resource. Those parts are only available to the video's owner.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at their docs you want to make the request like this:

```js
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos';

// These are the required query options
var requiredParameters = {
  part: 'snippet', //required, json form, use 'snippet'
  key: 'API_KEY', // required, put api key here, try to hide it
  id: '12345', // required, the video id
};


$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: url,
  params: requiredParameters
})
.then((response) => {

})
.catch((err) => {

})


/* Optional parameters
{
  h1,
  maxHeight,
  maxResults,
  maxWidth,
  onBehalfOfContentOwner,
  pageToken,
  regionCode,
  videoCategoryId
}
*/
```

Note: key parameter is used when not providing an OAuth 2.0 token. If you have a token, pass it in the header like this:

```
Authorization: 'Bearer oauth2-token'
```

Another way is to switch out 'key' for 'access_token' and put the OAuth 2.0 token there as a query parameter